# create a derived calss within the parent class in c++

Tags: c++, inheritance

In my program, I have a parent class and 2 derivetives of that class.
in a function (virtual one, different in each class/derivitve) I assign (using new) a var of the other classes. which, in result, causses compilations errors.
how can I fix it?

partial code:
parent class:

```
class client
{
protected:
    double surf_hours,disc_space,phone_time;
    string first_name,last_name;
public:
.
.
.
    virtual client* is_valid_plan()
    {
         client *B,*C;
         double client, business, company;
         client=compute_bill();
         B= new business(first_name,last_name,surf_hours,disc_space,phone_time);
         C= new company(first_name,last_name,surf_hours,disc_space,phone_time);
         .
         .
         .
};
```

derivative class #1:

```
class business:public client
{
public:
    business(string name, string last, double surf, double disc, double phone):client(name,last,surf,disc,phone){}
    client* is_valid_plan()
    {
         client *B,*C;
         double client, business, company;
         business=compute_bill();
         B= new client(first_name,last_name,surf_hours,disc_space,phone_time);
         C= new company(first_name,last_name,surf_hours,disc_space,phone_time);
         .
         .
         .
};
```

derivative class #2:

```
class company:public client
{
public:
    company(string name, string last, double surf, double disc, double phone):client(name,last,surf,disc,phone){}
    client* is_valid_plan()
    {
         client *B,*C;
         double client, business, company;
         company=compute_bill();
         B= new business(first_name,last_name,surf_hours,disc_space,phone_time);
         C= new client(first_name,last_name,surf_hours,disc_space,phone_time);
         .
         .
         .
};
```

Comment: When posting questions about compiler errors, please include the actual errors you get, complete, in full and unedited (and including any informational notes the compiler or linker gives you). Also please mark out in the code you show, for example with a comment, on which lines you get the errors.

Comment: However, in this case it would be easy to guess that you have circular include dependencies, leading to `business` and `company` and `client` being undeclared before you use those classes. My advice is to split the classes into separate class definition, and member function definition, together with forward declaring of the classes. I.e. separate the classes into a class definition in a header file, and member function definition (implementation) in a source file.

Answer (score 1):

You have a variable/class name conflict:

```
   double client, business, company;
                  ^^^^^^^^
   client=compute_bill();
   B= new business(first_name,last_name,surf_hours,disc_space,phone_time);
          ^^^^^^^^
```

choose a better name for your `business` variable. And the same issue is with the other variable names: `client` and `company`.